# Find the convergence area

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left({\frac{(4z+i)^n}{(2n+i)^2}}\right)$$
I've tried to use rule 
$$R = \frac{1}{\lim\sqrt[n]a}$$
but I don't know what to do with $z$ and $i$.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test

Answer (score 0):

I always tend to use the "ratio test" for problems like this.  We have $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}= \frac{(4z+ i)^{n+1}}{(2(n+1)+ i)^2}\frac{(2n+ i)^2}{(4z+i)^n}$
$= \left(\frac{4z+ i)^{n+1}}{4z+ i)^n}\right)\left(\frac{2n+i}{2n+2+i}\right)^2$
$= (4z+i)\left(\frac{2n+i}{2n+2+i}\right)^2$

Now, since the only dependence on "n" is the "2n" in both numerator and denominator of that fraction, that fraction goes to 1 as n goes to infinity and the limit is $4z+ i$ so we must have $|4z+ i|< 1$ or $|z+ \frac{i}{4}|< \frac{1}{4}$.  The region of convergence is the disk with center at $z= -\frac{i}{4}$ and radius $\frac{1}{4}$.

Answer (score 0):

Using the root test we find that the series converges whenever

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to \infty }\sqrt[n]{\left|\frac{(4z+i)^n}{(2n+i)^2}\right|}&=|4z+i|<1
\end{align}$$

and diverges whenever $|4z+i|>1$.

Note that on the circle $|4z+i|=1$, the series converges by comparison with $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}$.

> To summarize, the series converges whenever $|4z+i|\le 1$ and diverges elsewhere.

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can

Answer (score -1):

First, try to write your series as a classical, usual power series:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(4z+i)^n}{(2n+i)^2}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{4^n}{(2n+i)^2}\left(z+\frac i4\right)^n$$

and we thus have a power series around $\;z=-\cfrac i4\;$ and with general coefficient $\;\cfrac{4^n}{(2n+i)^2}\;$ , so

using Cauchy-Hadamard directly:

$$\frac1R=\limsup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{\frac{4^n}{|(2n+i)^2|}}=\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac4{\sqrt[n]{4n^2+1}}=4\implies R=\frac14$$

and thus our power series converges for all $\;\left|z+\cfrac i4\right|<\cfrac14\iff|4z+i|<1\;$ . As pointed out in other answer, the convergence extends to the circle $\;|4z+i|=1\;$ .

Comment: thank you, but one more question. How did u squared this one (2n+i)^2? where is 4ni?

Comment: @Ilya I just took the absolute value, o modulus, of those *complex numbers* . It is what must be done when trying to use some test for *positive (real) series* and the $\;n\,-$ th root one. Must probably whoever downvoted my answer doesn't even have any idea about this...